# Polldaddy doesn't show up on own theme

Tags: plugins, theme-development, loop, rating

I'm developing my own theme on a website where I use the polldaddy polls & ratings plugin. I've set the ratings to show up on the homepage and that's working with e.g. the twentytwelve theme. However with my own theme, I do see the polldaddy div, but there's nothing in it:

```
<div class="pd-rating" id="pd_rating_holder_5424010_post_653"></div>
```

This is my `index.php`:

```
<?php
get_header(); // Loads the header.php template. 
if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <div class="post_summary">
            <h2 class="post_title" id="post-<?php the_ID();?>"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; 
else : 
    get_template_part( 'loop-error' ); // Loads the loop-error.php template. 
endif; 
get_footer(); // Loads the footer.php template. 
?>
```

The `header.php` and `footer.php` just make a basic box model.

Then, the relevant codes of the polldaddy plugin, `ratings.php` (there is a filter addition on the bottom):

```
<?php
function polldaddy_show_rating_comments( $content ) {
    if ( !is_feed() && !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) {
        global $comment;
        global $post;

        if ( isset( $comment->comment_ID ) && $comment->comment_ID > 0 ) {
            $unique_id  = '';
            $title      = '';
            $permalink  = '';
            $html       = '';
            $rating_pos = 0;

            if ( (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-comments' ) > 0 ) {
                $rating_id = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-comments' );
                $unique_id = 'wp-comment-' . $comment->comment_ID;
                $rating_pos = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-comments-pos' );
                $title = mb_substr( preg_replace( '/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $comment->comment_content ), 0, 195 ) . '…';
                $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID ) . '#comment-' . $comment->comment_ID;
                $html = polldaddy_get_rating_code( $rating_id, $unique_id, $title, $permalink, '_comm_' . $comment->comment_ID );

                if ( $rating_pos == 0 )
                    $content = $html . '<br/>' . $content;
                else
                    $content .= $html;
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}

function polldaddy_show_rating( $content ) {
    global $wp_current_filter;
    if ( !in_array( 'get_the_excerpt', (array) $wp_current_filter ) ) {
        if ( !is_feed() && !is_attachment() ) {
            if ( is_single() || is_page() || is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() || is_category() ) {
                $html = polldaddy_get_rating_html( 'check-options' );

                if ( !empty( $html ) ) {
                    $rating_pos = 0;

                    if ( is_page() ) {
                        $rating_pos = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-pages-pos' );
                    } elseif ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() || is_category() ) {
                        $rating_pos = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-posts-index-pos' );
                    } else {
                        $rating_pos = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-posts-pos' );
                    }

                    if ( $rating_pos == 0 )
                        $content = $html . '<br/>' . $content;
                    else
                        $content .= $html;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;
}

function polldaddy_get_rating_html( $condition = '' ) {
    global $post;
    $html = '';

    if ( $post->ID > 0 ) {
        $unique_id = '';
        $title = '';
        $permalink = '';
        $rating_id = 0;
        $item_id = '';
        $exclude_posts = explode( ',', get_option( 'pd-rating-exclude-post-ids' ) );
        $exclude_pages = explode( ',', get_option( 'pd-rating-exclude-page-ids' ) );

        if ( is_page() ) {
            if ( !in_array( $post->ID, $exclude_pages ) ) {
                $unique_id = 'wp-page-' . $post->ID;
                $item_id =  '_page_' . $post->ID;
                if ( $condition == 'check-options' ) {
                    if ( (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-pages' ) > 0 ) {
                        $rating_id = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-pages-id' );
                    }
                } else {
                    $rating_id = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-pages-id' );
                }
            }
        } elseif ( !in_array( $post->ID, $exclude_posts ) ) {
            $unique_id = 'wp-post-' . $post->ID;
            $item_id =  '_post_' . $post->ID;
            if ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() || is_category() ) {
                if ( $condition == 'check-options' ) {
                    if ( (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-posts-index' ) > 0 ) {
                        $rating_id = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-posts-id' );
                    }
                } else {
                    $rating_id = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-posts-id' );
                }
            } else {
                if ( $condition == 'check-options' ) {
                    if ( (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-posts' ) > 0 ) {
                        $rating_id = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-posts-id' );
                    }
                } else {
                    $rating_id = (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-posts-id' );
                }
            }
        }

        if ( $rating_id > 0 ) {
            $rating_title_filter = get_option( 'pd-rating-title-filter' );

            if ( $rating_title_filter === false )
                $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $post->post_title, $post->ID, '' );
            elseif ( strlen( $rating_title_filter ) > 0 )
                $title = apply_filters( $rating_title_filter, $post->post_title, $post->ID, '' );
            else
                $title = $post->post_title;

            $permalink = get_permalink( $post->ID );
            $html = polldaddy_get_rating_code( $rating_id, $unique_id, $title, $permalink, $item_id );
        }
    }
    return $html;
}

/**
 * Construct a Polldaddy target div for a given rating_id and optional item_id
 * Define a Polldaddy ratings variable for a given rating_id and optional item_id
 *
 * @param int     $rating_id
 * @param string  $unique_id
 * @param string  $title     Post title
 * @param string  $permalink Post permalink
 * @param string  $item_id
 * @return HTML snippet with a ratings container and a related JS block defining a new variable
 */
function polldaddy_get_rating_code( $rating_id, $unique_id, $title, $permalink, $item_id = '' ) {   
    $html = sprintf( '[polldaddy rating="%d" item_id="%s" unique_id="%s" title="%s" permalink="%s"]', absint( $rating_id ), polldaddy_sanitize_shortcode( $item_id ), polldaddy_sanitize_shortcode( $unique_id ), polldaddy_sanitize_shortcode( $title ), polldaddy_sanitize_shortcode( $permalink ) );
    return do_shortcode( $html );
}

function polldaddy_sanitize_shortcode( $text ) {
    $text = preg_replace( array( '/\[/', '/\]/' ), array( '&#91;', '&#93;' ), $text );
    return esc_attr( $text );
}

if ( (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-pages' ) > 0 || (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-posts-index' ) > 0 || (int) get_option( 'pd-rating-posts' ) > 0 ) {
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'polldaddy_show_rating', 5 );
    add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'polldaddy_show_rating' );
}

add_filter( 'comment_text', 'polldaddy_show_rating_comments', 50 );
?>
```

How can I make the ratings show up right?

Comment: How do you add the extra code?

Comment: What extra code? The polldaddy div is just included by the plugin, I guess..? I didn't do anything about it. I think it's included in `the_excerpt()`? Or isn't that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, the exact hook and its callback function are the important bits here.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow you. Should I include another function to make the rating appear? If so, what function?

Comment: Somewhere in your code there is an `add_filter( 'the_content', 'some_function_name' );` or something very similar. We need that part to give an answer.

Comment: That's done in the polldaddy plugin. I added what I'd think is the relevant code to my question.

Comment: Does your `footer.php` include a call to `<?php wp_footer(); ?>`? If not, see @CamilStaps answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `wp_footer()` function has to be called in `footer.php`, just before closing the page with `</body>`.

Comment: I'm going to guess that this is the problem. We know the Plugin filter callback is working, because it is injecting the PollDaddy DIV. But PollDaddy's *scripts* are not firing - probably because they're not getting output. And if they're not getting output, it is probably because the Theme doesn't call `wp_footer()` in the footer. **Note: add `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` immediately before the *closing* HTML `</body>` tag.**

Comment: I think that was the problem, yes. I edited my answer accordingly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Sample of wp_footer()

```
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

Also check [wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_footer)